# No internet for clients pcs on Windows server 2003 domain

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have just set up new windows server 2003 server domain. My server is set as dhcp,dns server and active directory. I have also set forwarder on dns property as my router address and isp's dns appress.

Clients can join domain and get ip address without any problem, I can share files on server all goes without problem, but client computers does not get internet connectivity.

Again, if i set ip, subnet, gateway and dns manually it works but my clients pcs are not getting internet connection automatically after joining domain. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Compare the output of `ipconfig /all` when the machine receives an address from DHCP and when you are setting it manually.

You're probably missing some DHCP options on the scope or global config, like the gateway.